# What type is this run time error?

Tags: ios, swift3

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> ():
    0x1002582bc <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!
    0x1002582c0 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
    0x1002582c4 <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]
    0x1002582c8 <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #48]
    0x1002582cc <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #64]
    0x1002582d0 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #64              ; =64 
    0x1002582d4 <+24>:  mov    x19, x6
    0x1002582d8 <+28>:  mov    x20, x5
    0x1002582dc <+32>:  mov    x21, x4
    0x1002582e0 <+36>:  mov    x22, x3
    0x1002582e4 <+40>:  mov    x23, x2
    0x1002582e8 <+44>:  mov    x24, x1
    0x1002582ec <+48>:  mov    x25, x0
    0x1002582f0 <+52>:  adr    x8, #910208               ; protocol descriptor for Swift.CVarArg + 88
    0x1002582f4 <+56>:  nop    
    0x1002582f8 <+60>:  add    x0, x8, #16               ; =16 
    0x1002582fc <+64>:  movz   w1, #0x28
    0x100258300 <+68>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x100258304 <+72>:  bl     0x10025863c               ; rt_swift_allocObject
    0x100258308 <+76>:  mov    x26, x0
    0x10025830c <+80>:  stp    x22, x21, [x26, #16]
    0x100258310 <+84>:  strb   w20, [x26, #32]
    0x100258314 <+88>:  str    w19, [x26, #36]
    0x100258318 <+92>:  adr    x8, #910216               ; protocol descriptor for Swift.CVarArg + 136
    0x10025831c <+96>:  nop    
    0x100258320 <+100>: add    x0, x8, #16               ; =16 
    0x100258324 <+104>: orr    w1, wzr, #0x20
    0x100258328 <+108>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x10025832c <+112>: bl     0x10025863c               ; rt_swift_allocObject
    0x100258330 <+116>: mov    x8, x0
    0x100258334 <+120>: adr    x9, #220680               ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> ()).(closure #2)
    0x100258338 <+124>: nop    
    0x10025833c <+128>: stp    x9, x26, [x8, #16]
    0x100258340 <+132>: adr    x0, #467584               ; partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix ".507"
    0x100258344 <+136>: nop    
    0x100258348 <+140>: mov    x1, x8
    0x10025834c <+144>: mov    x2, x25
    0x100258350 <+148>: mov    x3, x24
    0x100258354 <+152>: mov    x4, x23
    0x100258358 <+156>: bl     0x10013be70               ; generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> (invoke : (Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x10025835c <+160>: brk    #0x1
```

Comment: Update your question with code.

Comment: Saw this issue today for the first time. A bit about my setup. Running Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62), macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555). In Xcode I have a Swift Error breakpoint set. Also I'm running on a device (5s). Unfortunately I did not run a backtrace once it happened so I dont know what triggered this. I will update with code if it happens again.